# Values are not iterated in a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

After initializing a HashMap, the values are inserted. But while trying to print the values, all the values are not printed. I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/girlfriends-demands/) problem.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = input.next();
        int cases = input.nextInt();
        long max = 0;
        HashMap<Long, Long> points = new HashMap<>();
        while(cases>0)
        {
            points.put(input.nextLong(), input.nextLong());
            cases--;
        }
        Iterator iterator = points.keySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            long x = (Long)iterator.next();
            long y = points.get(x);
            if(x>max)
                max = x;
            if(y>max)
                max = y;
        }
        while(inputString.length()<=max)
            inputString = inputString.concat(inputString);

        iterator = points.keySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            long x = (Long)iterator.next();
            long y = points.get(x);
            System.out.println("x: "+x+" y: "+y);
/*          if(inputString.charAt(new Long(x-1).intValue()) == inputString.charAt(new Long(y-1).intValue()))
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");*/
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

The values 2 and 4 are not printed. They are not iterated by the HashMap. What is the issue?

Comment: You don't need to store the input to solve that problem. Just examine the input and produce output per input line (and throw away the input).

Comment: Bohemian but I need to find the maximum number of times I need to duplicate and concatenate the string right. So for that purpose. Otherwise it tells time exceeded

Answer (score 5):

Map can have only one value per key.

If you put value 4 to key 2 and then you put value 5 to the same key you are overwriting the old value. Only the last one (5) remains in the map.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem is that you are using the wrong data structure. You don't use the fact that it is a map. You only use it as a list of points. The best solution is to replace it with a list of points, as illustrated in the following program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<int[]> points = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    points.add(new int[]{2,4});
    points.add(new int[]{2,5});
    points.add(new int[]{7,14});
    for(int[] point : points){
      int x = point[0];
      int y = point[1];
      System.out.println("x: "+x+" y: "+y);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
x: 2 y: 4
x: 2 y: 5
x: 7 y: 14
```